# Parsing json over XML

Tags: json, xml, parsing, go

I really don't understand how to parse this response from the Api using Go since I see XML first and then Json:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.zzap.ru/">{"error":"","class_man":"MITSUBISHI","logopath":"https://koj.blob.core.windows.net/zzap-upload/upload/logos/se12d7724469c1dbbe07e303ac6e91b48.png","partnumber":"MR245368","class_cat":"windscreen washer motor","imagepath":"","code_cat":1116901944,"class_cur":"р.","price_count_instock":24,"price_min_instock":200.0,"price_avg_instock":810.0,"price_max_instock":1380.0,"price_count_order":457,"price_min_order":201.0,"price_avg_order":1079.0,"price_max_order":8004.0,"imagepathV2":[""],"code_man":3113}</string>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Include your code. What problems did you encounter?

Comment: _"I see XML first and then Json"_ Then parse it as XML first and then as JSON.

Comment: since I'm just learning Golang I haven't found how to do it correctly

Comment: Do / learn it one at a time. First look for tutorials how to parse XML. Once you do it and you have the JSON value, then proceed as if you'd only have a JSON. There are numerous examples how to parse XML and JSON with Go.

Comment: I started with a description of type String struct but I didn't quite understand how to describe it correctly so if it was a regular XLM it wasn't a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will unmarshal the `xml` first and then unmarshal the `json` in the `Text` field of the `struct` the `xml` was unmarshalled to. Below is a link to the playground where you can run the example and play with it.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type xmlStructure struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"string"`
    Text    string   `xml:",chardata"`
    XMLNS   string   `xml:"xmlns,attr"`
}

type jsonStructure struct {
    Error      string `json:"error"`
    ClassMan   string `json:"class_man"`
    LogoPath   string `json:"logo_path"`
    PartNumber string `json:"part_number"`
    ClassCat   string `json:"class_cat"`
    // etc.
}

func main() {
    var input = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://www.zzap.ru/">{"error":"","class_man":"MITSUBISHI","logopath":"https://koj.blob.core.windows.net/zzap-upload/upload/logos/se12d7724469c1dbbe07e303ac6e91b48.png","partnumber":"MR245368","class_cat":"windscreen washer motor","imagepath":"","code_cat":1116901944,"class_cur":"р.","price_count_instock":24,"price_min_instock":200.0,"price_avg_instock":810.0,"price_max_instock":1380.0,"price_count_order":457,"price_min_order":201.0,"price_avg_order":1079.0,"price_max_order":8004.0,"imagepathV2":[""],"code_man":3113}</string>`

    var in xmlStructure
    if err := xml.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &in); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    var msg jsonStructure
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(in.Text), &msg); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v", msg)
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/2JaEMyRgj8X)

Note: The `jsonStructure` type is still missing some fields which where in your example.

Note2: Since you are new to Go:

The key to the problem is the xml and json tags behind the struct fields. They must match the field names of the xml/json input you get. For xml there are some special cases like the `xml.Name` type that is needed to match a struct to an xml tag. (By this the entire `xmlStructure` struct is matched to the `string` tag from the input.) Also the `xml:"xmlns,attr"` behind the `XMLNS` field tells the xml package to look for an attribute called `xmlns` in the `string` tag. The missing name in `xml:",chardata"` tells xml to select the content of the `string` tag.

The `json` tags are simpler, only stating the matching name in the input.

Also note, that the fields themselves of the structs must be exported, otherwise they are not accessible to the xml/json packages and cannot be filled.

Comment: I added some more explanation :)

Comment: thank you I read your explanation it helped me a lot